# how to embedd .swf which loads it's content from a xml file placed in another folder?

Tags: flash, actionscript

i am trying to embed .swf file on my web page.I know how to embed .swf file but my problem is that this .swf file loads it's contents from a xml file and i don't know to to add .swf with it's xml file.I tried many methods but still i am not able to run that swf file.

This myfile.swf and html file is stored in same folder and xml file is stored in 'content' folder,this code loads .swf file but does not take content from xml.Here is my code so far

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5</title>
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/swfobject.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" RIGHTMARGIN="0" TOPMARGIN="0" BOTTOMMARGIN="0">

    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/
       swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="movie" value="myfile.swf?xml_path=content/xml/mainXML.xml" />
    <param name='base' value='http://localhost/myproject/'>
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <embed src="myfile.swf?xml_path=content/xml/mainXML.xml" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowFullScreen="true" flashVars="xml_path=http://localhost/myproject/content/mainXML.xml"></embed>
    </object>

    </script>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: That should work if you did load the XML correctly ... Could you show us how did you loaded the XML file ?

Comment: that is the problem i am facing i don't know how to load xml file i found one answer and from that i think this statement loading xml ("myfile.swf?xml_path=content/xml/mainXML.xml) i am not sure..

Comment: NO. You should get the `xml_path` value (like [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) and the use it to load your XML file like [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6a.html) ... Try that, and if you still always have problems, put them here ...